# Java String replace method doesn't replace my '\' with '/' File Finder class

Tags: java, file, replace

my output has \.

my expected output is:

```
temp/F1.java
temp/F2.java
temp/subtemp/F3.java
```

What's wrong?..................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
public class FileFinder
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
       File dir1 = new File("temp");
       dir1.mkdir() ;
       File f1 = new File("temp/F1.java") ;
       f1.createNewFile() ;
       File f2 = new File("temp/F2.java") ;
       f2.createNewFile() ;
       File dir2 = new File("temp/subtemp") ;
       dir2.mkdir() ;
       File f3 = new File("temp/subtemp/F3.java") ;
       f3.createNewFile() ;
       find(dir1, ".java");
    }

    /**
       Prints all files whose names end in a given extension.
       @param aFile a file or directory
       @param extension a file extension (such as ".java")
    */
    public static void find(File aFile, String extension)
    {            
        //-----------Start below here. To do: approximate lines of code = 10
        // 1. if aFile isDirectory 
        if (aFile.isDirectory()) {
            //2. use listFiles() to get an array of children files 
            File[] children = aFile.listFiles();
            //3. use sort method of Arrays to sort the children 
            Arrays.sort(children);
            //4. for each file in the sorted children 
            for (File child : children) {
                //5. recurse  
                find(child, extension);
            }
        }//
        else {//
            //6. otherwise the file is not a directory, so 
            //use toString() to get the file name 
            String fileName = aFile.toString();
            //7. use replace() to change '\' to '/' 
            fileName.replace('\'' , '/');
            //8. if the file name endsWith the extension 
            if (fileName.endsWith(extension)) {
                //9. then print it.     
                System.out.println(fileName);
            }
        }
        //-----------------End here. Please do not remove this comment. Reminder: no changes outside the todo regions.
    }
}
```

Comment: If you look at the Javadocs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char, char) you will see that replace does not work with regular expressions.  Use replaceAll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the slash. Currently you're escaping a single quote instead.

Change:

```
fileName.replace('\'' , '/');
```

To:

```
fileName = fileName.replace('\\' , '/');
```

replace() doesn't change the value, you'd have to save it again which is what I did above.

Answer (score 0):

this code

```
fileName.replace('\'' , '/');
```

is changing a `'` to a `/` and to use replaceAll which uses regexp

what you want is

```
fileName.replaceAll("\\" , "/");
```

but actually - why bother with this code at all, you are not even saving the result of the replace.  For that you would need

```
fileName = fileName.replaceAll("\\" , "/");
```